# не работает selenium через jenkins

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Добрый день.
проблема такая: сделал автотест python+selenium. на локальном компьютере работает, на сервере при запуске руками работает, через jenkins не работает.
тест в том, что он прогружает сайт, авторизуется, делает несколько действий, переходит на одну из вкладок и по списку ищет элементы по xpath коду.
на компьютере, на сервере находит. через дженкинс все зависает на экране логин-пароля сайта, но ошибку не выдает нигде кроме как при нахождении элементов(прикрутил скриншот-мэйкер). между логин-паролем и поиском элемента программа делает несколько других действий и ошибку не выдает никакую, хотя на каждом действии(опять же по скриншотам) все тот же экран логин-пароля.

Comment: Могли бы Вы приложить лог jenkins? И может быть не хватает ожиданий? попробуйте что-то типа этого: `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "pass_id"))) driver.find_element_by_id('login').send_keys('login')`

Comment: лог не поможет. программа валится на assert по xpath, который ищет элементы на странице. везде отрабатывает кроме дженкинса. очень похоже как будто дженкинс "фризит" вид страници при первой загрузке, процессы остальные отрабатывают, а внешне это выглядит как страница с логином и паролем. у меня есть несколько assert- ов до глючного, по которым он проходит.

Comment: Может быть добавить `driver.maximize_window()` ? Дело может быть в том, что тест просто не видит искомые элементы страницы? Jenlins вообще где развёрнут локально ил на сервере где-то? Какая там ОС?

Comment: добавлял и кастомное разрешение и максимальное. на сервере. windows server 2012r    http://s018.radikal.ru/i526/1710/c3/3f5493027d73.png

http://s48.radikal.ru/i119/1710/db/79bd6c0e5605.png

Comment: Jenkins служба имеет доступ к операциям с рабочим столом? На wiki Jenkins нашел: **If the slave is supposed to start desktop applications you have to allow the service to interact with the desktop (Action->Properties->Logon->Allow service to interact with desktop).** Была у меня похожая проблема связанная с некликабельностью элементов. Jenkins их просто не видел/или они были "загорожены" другими элементами. В итоге всё решилось именно так как я описал выше.

Comment: у меня стоит использование учетной записи AD, которую я специально выделил для тестов.для такой настройки нет галочки.

Comment: Есть еще идеи у кого?

Comment: Сразу не заметил. Вы пишите "переходит на одну из вкладок", значит тест работает с несколькими вкладками в браузере? Т.е. открылась страница, он выполнил ряд действий, открыл ещё одну вкладку, продолжил выполнять действия уже с той вкладкой? Тогда он действительно может "не увидеть" нужные элементы, необходимо сделать вкладку активной для теста: `driver.execute_script("window.open('http://new_Tab.com','_blank');")
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])`

Comment: дико извиняюсь, это мой первый пост и вообще недавно в этой сфере. работаю на одной и той же вкладке. имел ввиду вкладки внутри сайта, для которого делаю автотест.

Answer (score 0):

Все решилось проще: jenkins запустили как приложение, а не как службу и он стал выполнять тесты визуально.
но есть проблема в том, что он не запускает тесты, если не находиться на сервере.